# How to access property value within a method

Tags: c#, properties, httpwebrequest

I am setting properties in GetData() Method and i want to get updated values of properties in all other methods within same class. It works with methods without httpWebRequest, httpWebResponse parameters while did not work in methods with httpWebRequest, httpWebResponseparameter. Please guide me how do i get properties values in methods with httpWebRequest, httpWebResponse Parameters.

```
  class ContentFetcher
  {
    Download download;
    private bool _IsEverything = false;

    public void GetData(Download download)
    {
      this.download = download;
      _IsEverything = download.IsEverything ;

      MessageBox.Show(_isEverything.ToString());    //output is "True"
    }

    public void ProcessHtmlContent(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(_IsEverything.ToString());   // Output is false while it should be true.
    }


    public void ProcessCssContent(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(_IsEverything.ToString());   // Output is false while it should be true.
    }

    public void FetchData(){
        ..........
        ..........
        ..........
     switch (getContentType(content_type_primary))
        {
            case "html":
                ProcessHtmlContent(request, response);
                break;
            case "javascript":
                ProcessJavascriptContent(request, response);
                break;
            case "image":
                ProcessImageContent(request, response);
                break;
            case "css":
                ProcessCssContent(request, response);
                break;
         }
      }
  }
```

I am calling GetData() in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public void StartDownloading()
{
        ..........
        ..........
        ..........
  Download download = new Download();
  download.IsEverything = true;

  ContentFetcher cf = new ContentFetcher();
  cf.GetData(download);
  cf.FetchData();
}
```

and in Download.cs

```
 private bool _IsEverything ;
        public bool IsEverything
        {
            get { return _IsEverything; }
            set
            {
                if (_IsEverything == value)
                    return;

                _IsEverything = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsEverything");
            }
        }
```

Comment: How did you call those methods?

Comment: @Win Please check now. I edited my question.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @john Saunders hmm thanks for title. Please help me. Solve my problem..

Comment: @Zohaib: I wish I could help, but I have no idea what you're asking about.

Comment: I am assigning value to a propety in GetData() method and want to get value of that property in other methods like ProcessHtmlConten(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response);

Comment: @Zohaib About code doesn't change the value of **_IsEverything**. Ideally, if you do not use **Download** inside **ContentFetcher** class, you only want to pass **boolean** to **GetData** method like this **GetData(bool isEverything)**.

Comment: I have no idea about .NET but in your `GetData`, is it correct to use `_IsEverything` instead of `this._IsEverything`? Are there no scoping issues occur?